# Getting a JSON from remote url in Visual Studio Xamarin is not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I started to learn Xamarin to develop application for iOS, Android and Windows Phone.

Seems a simple question but I don't know how to proceed with Xamarin.

I have the following lines of code:

```
public async Task<List<MyData>> GetItemsAsync()
{
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        try {
            string result = await client.GetStringAsync( "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1" );
            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result)) {
            }
        } catch( Exception ex ) {
            return await Task.FromResult(new List<MyData>(0));
        } finally {
            client.Dispose(); //of course, I can use `using`
        }

        return await Task.FromResult(new List<MyData>(0));
}
```

When debug in Visual Studio Android Emulator(`VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone (Android 6.0 - API 23)`), the line where starts with `string result` is stuck, nothing happens, no exception is thrown. I cannot use F10 in Visual Studio to inspect.

Also, I cannot use `WebClient` because System.Net doesn't include it.

Edit: If I remove `await` then I receive a general exception:

[image]

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: are you sure your URI is reachable from your device/emulator?  Have you waited to see if the request eventually times out?

Comment: yes, I tried myself and it is displayed accordingly in `Browser` browser.

Comment: I saw is issue with HTTPS, if I use `http` will work fine...How to solve for `https` issue ?

Comment: what is the inner exception of the aggregate exception?

Comment: `Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)`

Comment: @SnakeEyes make sure that you are *not* using the Mono managed httpclient & tls implementation, select the native provider: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/http-stack/ & https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/transport-layer-security/

Answer (score 0):

For those who meet the error:
`Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)`

Please use specific handler for Android:

```
using (HttpClient myClient = new HttpClient(new AndroidClientHandler())) { }
```

or for iOS:

```
using(HttpClient myClient = new HttpClient(new CFNetworkHandler())) {}
```

References:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/http-stack/
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/http-stack/